# Why is a forward declaration not enough even if the data type is never used

Tags: c++

*I know that similar questions have already been asked and there are answers describing that in the situations describe below forward declaration is not enough. However, these answers do NOT tell WHY it is not enough. Therefore, I don't think that this is a duplicated question.*

I have some difficulties to understand why the compiler has to see the definition of a data type (a foward declaration is not sufficient) in the following situation:

Let's consider we have a simple "main.cpp" as shown below, which does
absolutely nothing except including the header file "MyClass.hpp"

```
#include <MyClass.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Now, let's consider that the content of "MyClass.hpp" looks as follows:

```
#include <vector>

class Data1;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();                                      // default constructor
    MyClass(MyClass const & p_other);               // copy constructor
    MyClass(MyClass && p_other);                    // move constructor
    ~MyClass();                                     // destructor
    MyClass & operator=(MyClass const & p_rhs);     // copy assignment
    MyClass & operator=(MyClass && p_rhs);          // move assignment
private:
    Data1 *            m_a; // forward decl. always OK
    Data1              m_b; // forward decl. always not OK
    std::vector<Data1> m_c; // forward decl. OK if MyClass is not instantiated
};
```

MyClass contains several member variables:

- "m_a" is a pointer to "Data1",
- "m_b" is an instance of "Data1",
- "m_c" is a vector with elements of type "Data1".

The definition of "Data1" is neither included in "MyClass.hpp" nor in "main.cpp". It is just forward declared.

The compiler never has a problem with member variable "m_a", it doesn't require its definition for compiling "main.cpp" -- even if we would intantiate "MyClass".

Because we are not instantiating "MyClass", the compiler also doesn't have a problem with member variable "m_c". It also does not require the definition of "Data1" in this case.

However, the compiler has a problem with member variable "m_b":

> Impl1.hpp:16:24: error: field 'm_b' has incomplete type 'Data1'

My simple question is: why?

Please consider that we have user-defined default constructor, copy constructor,
move constructor, a user-defined destructor, and user-defined copy assigment
operator and move assignment operator, i.e., the compiler doesn't have to
generate code for any of these constructors/methods. So for what purpose does
the compiler need to see the definition of "Data1" when compiling only "main.cpp"?

Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: Hint: think about `sizeof(MyClass)` :)

Comment: I don't think that this answers my question. I already read the existing question and its answer. Why should sizeof(MyClass) be needed in this example? The main.cpp is totally empty and doesn't do anything!

Comment: @A.Schorr: in short, the layout of `MyClass` must be known at definition time and not usage time. As soon as you define it, even if its not ever used, its layout must be known.

Comment: main.cpp is not empty. You included MyClass.hpp. Which means that the whole text of MyClass.hpp is contained in main.cpp. It *does* nothing, just like a very long algorithm that returns nothing does nothing. That doesn't mean that this algorithm is allowed to use something that is not defined.

Comment: I perfectly understand that including a header file means that the whole text of MyClass.hpp is contained in main.cpp. However, this still doesn't answer my question. What exactly does the compiler do which requires to see the definition of "Data1"? (it is not required for compiling member variables "m_a" and "m_c")

Comment: It creates your class. There are no objects, but there is the class itself. A part of that is to define a bundle of types to be the associated data holder. It sees Data1* and thinks "okay, I need one variable that is a pointer, so I add 64bit (assuming a 64bit system), no problem." Then it looks at vector<Data1> and thinks itself "Hey, let's ask vector, what it needs", vector answers and has no problems itself since it manages over a pointer to Data1 itself. Then it sees Data1 and thinks "Okay, now, how much storage needs my bundle for Data1?", asks Data1 and gets no answer.

Comment: OK. The answer from Vittorio Romeo seems to be the explanation: "layout of MyClass must be known at definition time". One could still ask why it must be known at definition time, but I suppose this would require a rather long explanation about compiler construction. Thanks Vittorio.

Comment: Thanks also Aziuth.

Answer (score 0):

The size of `MyClass` depends on the size of `Data1`, which can only be known from the **definition** of `Data1`. That's why you cannot have incomplete types as fields in your types.

Comment: Some comment as for the answer above: Why is it necessary for the compiler to know the size of MyClass? It is never used anywhere!

Comment: because it's compiling the code you asked it to compile